# Обход Azure Loadbalancer

Tags: vpn, azure

Недавно с использованием vpn обнаружили, что ажуровский лоадбалансер в какой то момент начинает изменять запросы из приложения в aks. (с vpn все работает отлично)
Использовать все тот же vpn в проде не получиться в виду некоторых причин (как минимум, что любой vpn клиент требует root прав).
Нужно с минимальными телодвижениями обойти ажуровский лоадбалансер и не использовать рутовые контейнеры.
Может у кого-то есть опыт или какие-нибудь идеи? нужен тунель или еще что то но на уровне aks.

Comment: А что именно изменяется? Там же вроде tcp load balancer, он в содержимое запросов не лезет (а в случае https и не может влезть)

Comment: без впн в какой то момент запросы перестают ходить. с использованием впн все работает

Comment: Стоит в саппорт написать, а не искать обходной путь

Comment: Мы наступали на грабли с basic load balancer + несколько node pools, это был сетап по умолчанию некоторое время. Пишите в саппорт, они реально помогают